# Getting the maximum value from interrelated MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am trying to unify a pair of queries with a `LEFT JOIN`, so that I can perform an `ORDER BY` on a desired column.

Table A has an exclusive one-to-many relationship with Table B, and table B has an exclusive one-to-many relationship with Table C.

I want to get the maximum value of a column in Table C, for each row in Table A.

what I used to have was:

```
$tableA = SELECT * FROM tableA;
for each row in $tableA {
  $maxValue = SELECT MAX(value) FROM tableC WHERE tableB_id IN (SELECT tableB_id FROM tableB WHERE tableA_id={$row['tableA_id']}) GROUP BY tableB_id;
}
```

and now I'm thinking along the lines of:

`SELECT * FROM tableA LEFT JOIN (SELECT tableA_id, MAX(max_c_value) FROM (SELECT tableB_id, MAX(value) max_c_value FROM tableC GROUP BY tableB_id) t GROUP BY tableA_id) USING(tableA_id)`

but I know that's gibberish. I am not sure where to go from here.
I'm finding it hard to explain the problem, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT A.ID, MAX(C.MyField) as CField
FROM A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN B
        ON A.ID = B.A_ID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN C
                ON B.ID = C.B_ID
GROUP BY A.ID
```

You will get null value for CField if there is no rows corresponding.

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(table3.field),table1.field from table1
join table2 on table1.id=table2.table1_id
join table3 on table2.id = table3.table2_id
group by table1.field
```

Answer (score 0):

You were closer on the first try I think. You want something like this:

```
SELECT MAX(tableC.cValue) FROM tableA
LEFT JOIN tableB
  ON tableA.tableA_id = tableB.tableA_id
LEFT JOIN tableC
  ON tableB.tableB_id = tableC.tableB_id
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve it on my own, only to come back here and find I was making things far too complicated for myself, getting lost in a sea of tables!

This code did actually work, but I have already replaced it with the simpler code suggested above:

```
SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT A_ID, MAX(val) FROM (
    SELECT * FROM B LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT B_ID, MAX(val) val FROM C GROUP BY B_ID
    ) x USING(B_ID)
  ) y GROUP BY A_ID
) z USING(A_ID);
```

Comment: I love the `SELECT *` pattern!